# Correct mistake in $\int_0^73t^{2}dx = \left[ \frac{t^{3}} {3}\right]_0^{7} =\frac{343}{3}$

Tags: calculus

I need help with determine the charge after 7 seconds. The law of the graph is $I=3t^{2}$

I have got this far, but now not sure what to do next to finish it.

$$\int_0^7(3t^{2})dx = \left[ \frac{t^{3}} {3}\right]_0^{7} =\frac{343}{3}$$

From what I've read you need to subtract 2 fractions. To get the answer. But that is where I am stuck.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question at all ... (-1)

Comment: read your question and see if there enough information for others to understand what the hell you are talking about, then edit it again

Comment: If you have to compute $\int_0^7 3t^2\,dt$, then the answer is $[t^3]_0^7=343$.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't explain it so everyone understood it. I need to find the area under a graph of current against time. The law of the graph is $I=3t^{2}$. And I need to determine the charge after 7 seconds. I have got as far as I have put above. But now do not know what to do next. And was looking if anyone could help?

Comment: @Liam -  Can I suggest then that you edit your question to remove $f(3t^2)$ as it is confusing, you require the area under the curve of $f(t) = 3t^2$.

Comment: I have removed the f, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int 3 t^2 \, dt=t^3$$
Then you plug 7 and subtract what you get plugging 0, like this
$$\int_0^7 3 t^2 \, dt=\left.t^3\right|^7_0=343$$

Comment: Are you sure this is waht the OP was asking? What about the game-changing $f(3t^2)$?

Comment: I am sure the answer is 343. I am just not sure if my workings out are correct? I have seen a few different ways of finishing it. And it confused me.

Comment: So I do 7x7x7. Which is 343. Then 3x0. Which is 0. Which = 343. Is that the full workings out?